# Position of button changes when zooming IN and OUT : CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a button which should be places in right most corner, so I used CSS for that, in 100% zoom it works fine but when I give 75% zoom Out, it shows the button in middle, I tried giving `position` `fixed` / `absolute` / `relative`, but nothing worked.

Can someone help me please.

```css
.btn-primary {
    background: transparent;
    border-color: #2980b9;
    color: #2980b9;
    margin-left: 653px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn--rounded" id="AnchroTagForButton" name="submit" type="button" title="btn action">>>> Show Components<i class="btn-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Images while Zooming in and Out

100% ZOOM IN

[image: 100% ZOOM IN]

67% ZOOM IN

[image: 67% ZOOM IN]

Comment: Tru using percentage values instead of pixels

Comment: `653px` is a magic number. You shouldn't be positioning layout elements by shifting them off from the left side a specific amount. Look into flexbox.

Comment: % is not working @SalemJebnoun

Comment: btn-primary {
    background: transparent;
    border-color: #2980b9;
    color: #2980b9;
    /* margin-left: 653px; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
}                                                                                                                                                                       Is it like this , if yes am not getting it :( @JonUleis

Comment: In 100% zoom full page on my screen in Chrome it shows that centered - may give your some indication of a solution

Comment: you could try to add a bit more of info, which parent divs, if the site has a max-width... some more info, maybe the button is inside a div which has a max-width and when zooming out it's larger the viewport and gets shrinked to that view you are showing us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just need to set to `fixed` on it (unaffected by scrolling) since it is then out of the document flow. (might need `margin-right` but will leave that to you

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
.btn-primary {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: #2980b9;
  color: #2980b9;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn--rounded" id="AnchroTagForButton" name="submit" type="button" title="btn action">>>> Show Components<i class="btn-icon fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
```